# dynamic column with where clause in php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to write `query` like `select * from delivery where '$day' = 1`. I have to mention column name dynamically. but it's not working. I have mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun column in my table. that's why i need to run this query.

Comment: Show that actual code, plus explain whats not working - do you get an error message etc

Comment: Are you storing the timestamp of the delivery as well? Then you wouldn't really need to store days of the week, but instead just the timestamp. Then if you want all the deliveries on Monday, you could just extract the day value using DAY() in your where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try without the quote

```
select * from delivery where $day = 1
```